# Underground fiber installation terminologies

Tags: cable, fiber, optics

I am analyzing some documents from the city containing comments about underground network equipment installation. One of the comments that appear a lot is "MH ACCESS - ROD ROPE AND PLACE IPP". While MH Access refers to manhole access, it is not clear what the second half of the comment means. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: "rod" and "rope" probably refer to items for pushing and pulling cable.

Comment: @RonTrunk Thank you! Any ideas what IPP could mean. I found something relevant: Inlet and Pipe protection ([link](http://apps.dot.illinois.gov/eplan/desenv/061314/76G95-140/PLANS/11x17-061314-76G95-140-037-002.pdf)). Does that mean the enclosing case for cable?